# RAID 1 hard disks errors, file system is not mounting

Tags: debian, raid, hard-drive

I have a Server with 2 HDDs in soft RAID 1, the OS is Debian Wheezy. After some database testing, the file system has gone to read-only mode, after which I have rebooted the machine. The server is not starting again, so I have booted a rescue system to look after the HDDs.

Now the problems start: `fdisk -l` is giving no output, and `fdisk /dev/sda` says `Unable to read /dev/sda`, while `smartctl -a` gives me a `SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED`. All the problems occur with /dev/sdb as well.

`mdadm` isn't helpful as well:

```
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sda
mdadm: /dev/sda has no superblock - assembly aborted
```

Output from `dmesg`:

```
ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata5.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata5.00: cmd c8/00:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 4096 in
res 61/04:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
ata5.00: SB600 AHCI: limiting to 255 sectors per cmd
ata5.00: SB600 AHCI: limiting to 255 sectors per cmd
ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata5: EH complete
```

`testdisk` is listing the drives with the correct size, but when I am trying to test the disk, every block is return a read error:

```
...
file_pread(4,2,buffer,34(0/0/35)) read err: Input/output error
file_pread(4,8,buffer,32(0/0/33)) read err: Input/output error
file_pread(4,8,buffer,40(0/0/41)) read err: Input/output error
file_pread(4,3,buffer,48(0/0/49)) read err: Input/output error
...
```

I am a bit puzzled, because I doubt that both disks have died at the same time and I suspect, that the SATA-controller may have some problems. How can I test this? And what else can I check?

Comment: Under normal conditions `/dev/sda` cannot be a MD base device thus it's not surprising that `mdadm` doesn't find a superblock. Does `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` give usable output? What happens if you execute `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null count=1`?

Comment: Show the smartctl results in your question.

Comment: @psusi If just the MBR sector broke then SMART will probably not detect that.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, of course it will?

Comment: @psusi OK, that was bad wording (maybe even party bad thinking): SMART will notice one failed sector and increase that counter but it will not treat that as a severe error, will not report the disk as failing or the like. I assume that SMART treats the MBR like any other sector. It broke and gets remapped when written. But as it is the MBR this error though irrelevant to the disk crashes the whole system.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, hence why I asked for the *full* smartctl output.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: `/dev/sda` _can_ be an md base device.  My understanding is that it's only recommended that you use partitions (e.g. `/dev/sda1`) to avoid problems when replacing a bad disk with a disk that is not precisely the same size (or larger) than the disk being replaced.  While it's good practice, using the raw disk shouldn't cause any other problems.

Comment: @s.co.tt I wrote "Under normal conditions" meaning that if sda is a MD base device then you cannot boot from it (without really evil hacking). No regular PC boots a disk that doesn't have a partition table. Having a partition table **and** using the whole device as MD base device would seem really crazy to me for a whole bunch of reasons.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: I think I was interpreting your comment too broadly.  Indeed you are correct when it comes to boot disks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was no problem with the HDDs neither with the controller. It was... the SATA cable.

Lesson for me (and everybody else): Before trying everything and wasting hours of time, first check the very obvious things.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend to rebuild the array with the second hard disk and make a backup if you don't have one. Probably something like that:

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb1 missing
```

Then after exchanging the first hard disk, you should be able to copy the partition table

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sdb | sfdisk /dev/sda
```

and add the new harddrive to the array again

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sda1
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sda1
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sda1
```

If you have more than one partition just do this for all partitions (marking faulty and removing)

Comment: Oh, I guess I haven't made it clear enough that I have the same problem with both disks. /dev/sdb isn't reading any blocks either.

Comment: Oh OK, I thought there is only one hard disk effected. My bad. Do you have any possibility to check them in another server? I would say as well, very unlikely that both hard drives crash at the same time and you're not able too read from one of them. Could be just a faulty controller / hardware error.